# Canonical commutation relations for a real scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, commutator

I am taking my first course in QFT and have come across this problem

> From the canonical commutation relations for a real scalar field $\hat{\phi}$  show that 
>   $$[\partial_i \hat{\phi} , \hat{\phi}] = 0,$$
>   where $i$ is a spatial index.

I have had an attempt but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is allowed. What I did is

The cannonical commutation relation tells us

$[ \hat{\phi} (x^0,x^i) , \hat{\phi}(x^0,x^{'i})] = \hat{\phi} (x^0,x^i)\hat{\phi} (x^0,x^{'i})-\hat{\phi} (x^0,x^{'i})\hat{\phi} (x^0,x^{i})= 0 $

Taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$

$\frac{\partial \hat{\phi} (x^0,x^i)}{\partial x_i}\hat{\phi} (x^0,x^{'i})-\hat{\phi} (x^0,x^{'i})\frac{\partial \hat{\phi} (x^0,x^i)}{\partial x_i}= 0$

Then set $x'=x$

$[\partial^i \hat{\phi} (x^0,x^i),\hat{\phi} (x^0,x^i)]=0$

Comment: have a loot at the threads [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/what-is-the-commutator-of-an-operator-and-its-derivative) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340491/commutator-of-scalar-field-and-its-spatial-derivative), I think you will find your answer.

Comment: Thanks Vangi I understand now